# Can't Pass String as parameter JSF 2.3

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces, viewparams, jsf-2.3

I'm using `Primefaces 6.0` and `JSF 2.3`, i passed String as parameter but it become empty!
java:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext extContext = context.getExternalContext();
String redirected = extContext.encodeActionURL(context.getApplication().getViewHandler().getActionURL(context, url));

URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(redirected);
builder.addParameter("action", "A")
extContext.getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
extContext.redirect(builder.toString());
```

XHTML:

```
......
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="action" value="#{mybean.action}" />
</f:metadata>
.......
```

It works fine when i pass Boolean or Long, below an example Long :

```
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{mybean.id}" converter="javax.faces.Long" />
```

Comment: Did it work in JSF 2.2? (I'm asking since you explicitly state it does not work in 2.3) And **where** does it become empty? In the URL? In the redirected page with the viewParam?

Comment: It become empty in the redirected page but i'm using Omnifaces and it works fine now, thank you a lot :)

Comment: @SidaouiMajdi You should post your final solution below for others to see even if it was to switch to Omnifaces o:viewParam.

Comment: @Melloware Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added OmniFaces library and it works very well :

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
   <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

XHTML:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
//Add this tag
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

......
<f:metadata>
    <o:viewParam name="action" value="#{mybean.action}" />
</f:metadata>
.......
```